# is not abstract and does not override abstract method onError(Exception) in Callback

Tags: java, android

I am trying to solve the following problem with my Android app:

```
error: <anonymous org.xxx.xxx.add.ScanActivity$1> is not abstract and does not override abstract method onError(Exception) in Callback
```

with the following code:

```
  final ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        Picasso.with(ScanActivity.this)
                .load(token.getImage())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.scan)
                .into(image, new Callback() { // anonymous class derived from Callback() must be abstract error
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        findViewById(R.id.progress).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        image.setAlpha(0.9f);
                        image.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                finish();
                            }
                        }, 2000);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                        finish();
                    }
                });
    }
```

Could you help me fix the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Look carefully what signature the `onError` method has in exception message. Then look at how your code defined it.

Comment: This really must be a dupe ...

Answer (score 2):

In *Java* the signature of a methods matters. `onError()` is not the same as `onError(Exception)`.

So you actually need to override `onError` with a single `Exception` parameter.

```
@Override
public void onError(Exception e) {
    finish();
}
```

You can read more about it on [Defining Methods - Overloading Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html).

Answer (score 0):

Replace your onError implementation with something like this:

```
@Override
public void onError(Exception e) {
    finish();
}
```